# Max Lange Attack - Materials to Study

Tags: opening, books

I am looking for quality materials such as books, magazines and video series to help me to study Max Lange Attack. I'll be grateful if you recommend one and share the link.

Answer (score 6):

Two other sources:

*Dangerous Weapons: 1 e4 e5* (2008) by Emms, Flear and Greet has a chapter on the variation with `8. fxg7`.

*Beating the Open Games* (2007) by Marin also has a chapter on the Max Lange Attack. The nice thing about the latter book is that you can find an [update for free](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/productimages/cms/pdf/opening/BTOG_Update.pdf) at [the site of the publisher](https://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/1/2/beating_the_open_games_-_2nd_edition_by_mihail_marin/). The Max Lange Attack is discussed from page 35 in the pdf document.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsLWP611jOM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrkyE78II-M are decent.  There are other videos on youtube, but most of them are cheap opening traps.

A Startling Chess Opening Repertoire by Chris Baker only has one chapter and just covers the basics.

Winning With the Giuoco Piano and the Max Lange Attack by Andrew Soltis is better, but still only good for people under 2000.

Answer (score 1):

The book "An Opening Repertoire for the Attacking Player" by Raymond Keene and David Levy covers the Max Lange as the "backbone of the repertoire". The book was published in 1984 and is now out of print but [Amazon lists several second hand copies](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Opening-Repertoire-Attacking-Player/dp/0713445866) available. I based my repertoire around this book in the 1980's and rated it highly. It is probably a bit out of date now but could give you an interesting aggressive way of looking at the opening.

Comment: Thanks, outdated but still looks like a good resource.